# Cannot_register user in ejabberd-21 (unknown virtual host)

Tags: ejabberd

I'my trying to simply register user using `ejabberdctl`:

```
ejabberdctl register admin 100.100.100.100 123456
```

and receive: `unknown virtual host` - same for every user.

**Configuration:**

*ejabberd.yml*:

```
hosts:
  - "100.100.100.100"

auth_method:
    -sql
    -external
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1   100.100.100.100
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

No errors in log files both in `/opt/ejabberd/logs` and `/var/log/`

No errors in `debug` mode.

ejabberd version - 21.07

Answer (score 0):

I followed your configuration, with only this change (I don't have SQL or extauth configured):

```
auth_method:
  - internal
```

And it works correctly:

```
ejabberdctl register admin 100.100.100.100 123456
User admin@100.100.100.100 successfully registered
```

Can you configure like I do, only internal, and check again?

If it works with internal, then enable only sql. Does it work?

If it works with sql, enable only external. Does it work?

If it works, then enable both sql and external as you desired. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks for response. It doesn't work (or I think so), because ejabberd still got default vhost. Result of "ejabberdctl registered_vhosts" gives me "jab2021". "Hosts" in yml should effect on it?

Comment: Works now. There was two config files. in /opt/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml and /ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml. I don't know why there was two of them

Answer (score 0):

```
ejabberdctl register <username> <custom_hostname> <your_custom_password>
```

it works and will create an account like:

hostname: `<username>@<custom_hostname>`

password: `<your_custom_password>`